# Xcode color asset catalog and dark appearance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOcCc.png)
Anybody knows how can be setup small icon of colorSet in left asset catalog panel (in red circle on example image) in the same color as "Any Appearance" color, not as "Dark Appearance" color?

By default it looks the same as "Dark Appearance"color when my Mac has Dark Mode and looks the same as "Any Appearance" color when my Mac has Light Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from attrribute inspector.

[image]

Comment: I mean just appearance of icon in asset catalog (it is in red circle on example image), when I have colorSet with two colors for Any and Dark, icon in the asset catalog has color the same as Dark, I want it to be as Any color, not Dark.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the RGB settings below the appearance selector. I'm not positive though.